# How can I make an old file easily readable?

Tags: notepad++, encoding, binary-files

I have this old .dat file (mid 90s), apparently encoded in ANSI, 4000 lines, consisting mostly of controls like `NUL`, `SOH`, `ETX`, `STX`... that I'd like to read.

I tried to convert it to UTF-8 with Notepad++, some controls like `NUL` get removed  but there are a lot left.
I also tried to search and replace these controls but they don't get caught by the search funtion.

How should I proceed to make this file humanly readable ?

EDIT for more details :
This file comes from a software written in Borland C/C++ 2.0, developed by someone in the company I'm working for (as an intern). This person is not here anymore and the software has been running since 1996 on a super old computer running MS-DOS and has a super crucial role for the company's business.
I'm in charge of redoing that software using .NET technologies, databases... which is done but now I need this file called `STOCK.DAT` that the old sotware uses to write/read all the stock data.

Using a hex editor, the first bytes are `30 35 30 00 20 33 35` which correspond to `050. 35` in the file, followed only by `00` until the text starts.

Comment: Presence of non-printable bytes in a file almost always indicates this is *not* a text file, even though it may contain text data. You need to look at the original source code.

Comment: This is a "_binary_" file, and you won't be able to make sense of it with a text editor. If you could use a hex editor (e.g: HxD) to share the first ~32 bytes with us, we might be able to help identify what type of file it is and suggest ways to view it... but it's quite likely a bespoke format which we won't be able to help with - inspect the original source code.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like either a binary file or created by an obscure editor product.
The postfix `.dat` is usually used for binary files or for email attachments.

If you would like to examine the readable strings inside the file,
you may use the free
[Sysinternals Strings](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/strings).

The file-type can sometimes be analyzed from the first few bytes.
If you wish us to have a look, please add here a hex dump of the beginning of this
file.

Comment: Thanks for `Strings` it made the file actually readable. It also looks like it misinterprets some stuff as some parts (numbers) appear removed. I also edited the original post in case it helps.

Comment: So this is really a binary file. The numbers are possibly in binary form.